Brainstorm for boosting graduation qualifications
As we all know, we have very few questions per day. A lot of users log on, ask a question, and never return. Furthermore, a large number of questions are robotics or basic technology only.
However! We are still in beta. The number of views, users, and questions with answers may be greatly increased if we can reach full site status.

Check it out! We are actually doing well in three categories, fine in another. All we need is for our multiple hundred users to ask more questions and not be afraid to post answers, and we can move to the point where we can be a full site with more people, moderators, and all the other benefits.
Question: How do we get more questions and answers?
(May be rhetorical. Try it!)

Advertise at conventions.  I will be adding a QR code for bricks.SE to all my GBC modules.  Even though it says our numbers of users are "Excellent", I think adding more users will be the biggest help in boosting the other stats.

Having a 'core' community helps - I've been a mod 'pro tem' on SR.SE, and have involvement in a few other sites, and I've found some degree of activity in chat is pretty nice for this. Something like this would come up in chat, people talk about it (and other things!) and bounce ideas off each other in realtime. I for one, will try to pop into the chat for the next month or so, so there's at least someone on when people come in. 
There's a few advantages to this - sometimes we share questions we come across where someone on chat is a subject matter expert, and you get pretty good retention if you get the right sense of community on.
That said, lego is a strange topic , since you either freestyle the hell out of things (Moocs!) or use the usually very clear instructions to build as per designs. A lot of existing questions are "identification type" questions (which are an oddity - and a generic question is what many sites do).
I suppose a 'related' question might be 'what sort of questions do I want to see here?' I'd love to see more questions over advanced techniques like building large curved structures. Would questions to do with the use of whatever's the design software people use these days (in my day it was lcad and various wrappers for that) be on topic, and would they be handy ?
My one question here so far involved a step I was stuck in - and I got an answer fast, things are good there. 
